# jQuery click does not work on append

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('.spinner').on('click', '.btn:first-of-type', function() {
  var $input = $(this).closest('.numeric-btn').find('.spinner input');
  $input.val( parseInt($input.val(), 10) + 1).keyup();
});
```

When I replace `div` where is `.spinner` class with

```
$('.side-form > div.cart-form').replaceWith(cart_form);
```

Then click event does not work. What can be the problem ?

Comment: @Andrey I'm gonna bookmark that link - there's at least 10 questions like this every day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind the delegate to something higher in the DOM.

You could use `$(document)`, but I would target the next parent up from where  you are doing your DOM manipulation.  As an example:

```
<div id='container-parent'>
    <div class='spinner'>
        <div class='btn btn-default'>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then you could bind to 'container-parent':

```
$('#container-parent').on('click', '.btn:first-of-type', function(){...}
```

That should allow the delegate to stay remain intact.

Comment: Thanks only your example works correctly.